Keras model building get error Cannot convert '51' to a shape
I am making a keras model to classify Human pose. I have taken the code from the link
In Colab it is working fine. I get below error in my local
Cannot convert '51' to a shape.
def landmarks_to_embedding(landmarks_and_scores):
  """Converts the input landmarks into a pose embedding."""
  # Reshape the flat input into a matrix with shape=(17, 3)
  reshaped_inputs = keras.layers.Reshape((17, 3))(landmarks_and_scores)

  # Normalize landmarks 2D
  landmarks = normalize_pose_landmarks(reshaped_inputs[:, :, :2])

  # Flatten the normalized landmark coordinates into a vector
  embedding = keras.layers.Flatten()(landmarks)

  return embedding

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(51))
embedding = landmarks_to_embedding(inputs)

layer = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu6)(embedding)
layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(layer)
layer = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu6)(layer)
layer = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(layer)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(class_names), activation="softmax")(layer)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()


At which point you encountered the error? Check the data loading pipeline. Also, please share the full reproducible code.

Hi, could you please provide the code for the normalize_pose_landmarks. Not able to run your code without it. thx
